# Download base64 pdf with IE9

Tags: javascript, pdf, internet-explorer-9, base64

I have a base64 pdf that I get from external system.
I want to be able to download this pdf in IE9 with JavaScript and this is a problem since IE9  doesn't support DATA URI for pdf.

Please help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Adobe Flash based plugin [Downloadify](http://davidwalsh.name/downloadify) (see the [demo](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/downloadify.php)) to allow users download file in IE9.

You may check if the current browser supports dataURI or not using the following js function:

```
function CheckDataURISupport(){

var result = true;
var checkDataURISupportImage = new Image();

checkDataURISupportImage.onload = checkDataURISupportImage.onerror = function(){
    if(this.width != 1 || this.height != 1){
        result = false;
    }
}
checkDataURISupportImage.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=";
// check if we have datauri support in current browser - end

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to use Downloadify but with no success. Can you give me an example please? I have base64 pdf that returns to js code from an external system.

Comment: check this online sample (see the source code of the page and see  function CreatePDFDownloadifyButton implementation, you just need to set PDFContentBase64 to the string with base64 encoded pdf file you have from external system):  http://bytescout.com/files/help/BytescoutPDFGeneratorSDKJS/draw-invoice-with-table-and-logo/sample.html (Disclosure: I work for ByteScout but this sample code is free to use)

Comment: great, if it works then please mark the answer as worked so other may use it as well.

Comment: I have one more question, maybe you can help me. I want to change the button image to my image. Do you know how can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: it is possible but it requires you to recompile Downloadify swf with the replaced button image, see the source code of it at https://github.com/dcneiner/downloadify

Answer (score 0):

`Downloadify.js` is a great solution for your case. Just be careful with options. There should be

```
'dataType': 'base64'
'data:' string representation of pdf in base64 format
```

Also be sure that your link/button has inserted 'flash code' by downloadify plugin (check source code after `downloadify.create()` initialization). Also you can check if your base64 has `data:application/pdf;base64,` type at the beginning.